# How to export a Numpy array to Comsol?

Tags: python, numpy, comsol

I have a Python script that creates a numpy array. How should I save this Numpy array to disk so that it can be read by Comsol?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the format your software needs.
If you just want them in one line concatenated by commas, you do it like this:

```
your_array = [1, 2, 3] # works the same for numpy array
your_seperator = "," # for new line use "\n"

with open("path/to/your/file/your_array.txt", "w") as output_file:
    output_file.write(your_seperator.join(your_array)
```

Alternatively:

```
np.savetxt("your_array.csv", your_array, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: If the Numpy array is 3D, is there a way to keep this shape? Or do I have to do it manually in Comsol?

Comment: it really depends on what your tool is expecting. you can try the default numpy savetxt function (see my updated answer)